# Data Type Mismatch on SQL Replace

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have four (relevant) fields, `DESCRP`, `Description1`,`Description2` and `DescriptionMatch`.

`DESCRP` should be the same as `Description1` padded to 18 characters + `Description2`. This is getting verified during this process.

The below code works fine as long as `Description2 IS NOT NULL`.

```
UPDATE tblParametersComp SET DescriptionMatch = "YES" 
WHERE (NOT (DESCRP IS NULL OR Description1 IS NULL))
AND
((DESCRP  = [Description1]+IIf(Len([Description1])<18,Space(18-Len([Description1])),"")+[Description2])
```

For some reason, this doesn't work if `Description2 IS NULL` so I am trying to add this line to remedy this (as the padding is irrelevant if there is no second line:

```
OR Description2 IS NULL AND REPLACE(Description1," ","") = Replace(DESCRP," ",""))
```

However, this is generating the following error:

[image: DB Error]

Which makes no sense, because as far as I can see, all of the relevant fields are of the `Text` data type.

[image: DB Data]

I've tried using `CSTR(Replace(...)) = CSTR(Replace(...))` just to be sure and that made no difference.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: At the final, substitute + Description2 for + (Description2 + "")

Comment: Sadly, this hasn't helped

Comment: Utilize the same IIF() in Description2.

Comment: That doesn't work either: thanks though. The thing that I don't understand is why Replace() is giving me data mismatch errors

Comment: Try: AND IF ISNULL(Description2, " ") Returns " "

Comment: Still no joy... I can't understand why this isn't working

Comment: Is the Description2 field in database set to ALLOW NULL ?

Comment: Presumeably so... I haven't changed it from default and lots of them are empty

Comment: Is Description2 sometimes `Null` or is it sometimes an empty string? Your replace isn't handling nulls currently

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't aware that there was a distinction in access... That'll be it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in the comments, and nobody posting a definitive answer, the issue seems to be not handling `NULL` records.

This was dealt with using the `NZ` function.

So the line became:

`WHERE DESCRP  = nz([Description1],"")+IIf(Len(nz([Description1],""))<18,Space(18-Len(nz([Description1],""))),"")+(nz(Description2,""));`

Which works like a charm!